# python odo sql AssertionError: datashape must be Record type, got 0 * {...}

Tags: python, mysql, odo, datashape

I'm trying to import a CSV into MySQL using odo but am getting a datashape error.

My understanding is that datashape takes the format:

```
var * {
    column: type
    ... 
}
```

where var means a variable number of rows.  I'm getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: datashape must be Record type, got 0 * {
  tod: ?string,
  interval: ?string,
  iops: float64,
  mb_per_sec: float64
}
```

I'm not sure where that 0 number of rows is coming from.  I've tried explicitly setting the datashape using `dshape()`, but continue to get the same error.

Here's a stripped down version of the code that recreates the error:

```
from odo import odo

odo('test.csv', mysql_database_uri)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.6.1 using Conda.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: I ended up not using odo for this since I couldn't find a fix in the timeframe I needed.

Comment: See an answer here: https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/580

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, needed to specify table

```
# error
odo('data.csv', 'postgresql://usr:pwd@ip/db')

# works
odo('data.csv', 'postgresql://usr:pwd@ip/db::table')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
odo('test.csv', mysql_database_uri)
```

with

```
odo(pandas.read_csv('test.csv') , mysql_database_uri)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up not using odo in my code so I can't test whether or not this corrects the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Odo seems to be buggy and discontinued. As an alternative you can use [d6tstack](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-sql.ipynb) which has [fast pandas to SQL functionality](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-sql.ipynb) because it uses native DB import commands. It supports Postgres, MYSQL and MS SQL,

```
cfg_uri_mysql = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://testusr:testpwd@localhost/testdb'
d6tstack.combine_csv.CombinerCSV(glob.glob('*.csv'), 
    apply_after_read=apply_fun).to_mysql_combine(uri_psql, 'table')
```

Also particularly useful for importing multiple CSV with data schema changes and/or preprocess with pandas before writing to db, see further down in [examples notebook](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-sql.ipynb)